# Batch script to execute a Python script multiple times

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I need to run a Python script N times, so I created the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd PATH_TO_SCRIPT
@set port=5682
set /P INPUT=Number of servers: 
FOR /L %%I IN (1, 1, %INPUT%) DO (
    @set /a newport=%port%+1
    start cmd /k > start python server.py -i 192.168.1.2 -p %newport%
)
pause
```

If I enter **1** as input value, such that there is only one iteration, the script works, but if I choose 2, the script only runs one instance of the server and tells me: "Unable to access file. The file is used from another process". What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you redirecting output to a file named "start"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd PATH_TO_SCRIPT
set port=5682
set /P INPUT=Number of servers: 
set /a newport=%port%
FOR /L %%I IN (1, 1, %INPUT%) DO ( 
   set /a newport+=1
   start cmd /k > start python server.py -i 192.168.1.2 -p !newport!
)
pause
```

Logic error : On each iteration, you are adding 1 to `PORT`, but `port` never changes. You need to initialise `newport` to the value of `port` and increment `newport`.

Minor style problem: `@` is not required after `@echo off`. `echo off` turns OFF command-reporting. `@` before a command turns command reporting OFF for *that command* only

Major problem : Please see the many, many articles on SO about *delayed expansion*. In essence, `%var%` refers to the value of `var` as it was set at the **start** of the loop and if you want to access the value as it changes within the loop, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` and use `!var!`

Your problem to fix: the `cmd /k` is not required, and the `>` is, as pointed out already, bizarre.

Also, your logic would start numbering at 5683 because you add 1 *before* invoking the `start`. May or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out already, in your FOR loop, %newport% resolves to [empty] upon execution. It's because newport isn't set until AFTER cmd resolves %newport%, since the entire FOR loop is one statement. In other words, %newport% gets resolved before the commands in the loop are executed, which means it's not set yet, and /p gets nothing. So presumably it uses the same port each time.

You don't have to use delayed expansion, though. You could just use your FOR /L iterator (%%I). I think this would be simpler.

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL
CD PATH_TO_SCRIPT
SET /P INPUT=Number of servers: 
SET /A END=5682+%INPUT%-1
FOR /L %%I IN (5682, 1, %END%) DO ( 
   START python server.py -i 192.168.1.2 -p %%I
)
PAUSE
```

Also, I agree that it is strange that you're redirecting the output to a file named start. I think you must have been trying to do something else.